# image viewer in ubuntu that can show the pixel coordinates and pixel value as well for current mouse location in the image

Tags: opencv

I am looking for any image viewer in ubuntu which can show the pixel coordinates and pixel value under current location of mouse other than gimp.....
thanks for your help

Comment: `Pinta` might be what you want; it's in the repositories, although you might want to compile a more recent version if you are running 12.04.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[edisplay](http://exactcode.com/opensource/exactimage/) will do it. Moreover, it gives RGB values and can focus, it is in the standard Ubuntu repository. Just install it via terminal:

```
$ sudo apt-get install edisplay
```

And for opening your images on it use this command:

```
$ edisplay --gl /path/to/image
```

Comment: It's not in the Ubuntu repository anymore, 22.04, for instance